# Poor performance with AMD R7 M265 after driver upgrade/system restore

Tags: drivers, windows-10, graphics-card, performance, freeze

I have a very strange problem.

It happened two weeks ago, when Radeon Crimson was released. I ran DDU and wiped my old Catalyst install (it was working fine). After that, I installed the latest drivers, rebooted and tried to run GRID.

The game stuttered too much, mainly in the cut-scenes. I should get a steady 30FPS at them, but instead got 15FPS and stuttering. And while in-game, things render well, and my FPS is normal -- for 2 to 3 seconds. After that, it freezes for a second then runs fine again, and then it freezes, and then it runs fine, etc.

Reverting the driver solved this issue.

Skip a little while, I decided to restore my computer to factory settings (it was working fine). I start the restore process in Windows, and after it has finished, I install the factory (stock) drivers for my video card. The stuttering had returned, same thing as the one two weeks ago.

I tried upgrading the drivers to Crimson: nothing.

I tried to install a driver from the Windows' repositories: nothing.

I tried reverting the driver to the initial version: nothing.

What can I do to try and get my video card up-and-running fine again?

Specs:

- Intel Core i5 4210U
- 8GB RAM
- AMD Radeon R7 M265 2GB
- Windows 10 Build 10586
- If it helps, it's a Dell Inspiron 15 5547-A10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, somehow.

For some reason, the latest beta driver and the latest crimson driver aren't coping with my R7. It introduces massive stutter on ANYTHING rendered by the dedicated graphics card. Either the framerates on both cards are conflicting or maybe it's an issue with the latest Mantle driver; I have yet to get an answer from AMD. Integrated Video Card (Intel HD 4000) is working fine, regardless of the AMD driver.

But, here's how to fix it:

Uninstall the graphics card drivers from Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`), remember to mark the "Delete this driver" box. After that, run DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) to get your system cleaned of any remaining traces of the crimson driver. Finally, download and install the stock drivers from Dell (15.20.1045-150622a-1859-18C-Dell). Those are the latest stable drivers supplied by AMD, any other driver (incluiding the crimson ones) won't like your card and reject it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your R7 m265 doesnt work with the Windows 10 Driver from Windows. 
You have to go to your Device-Manager, search for your 265m and.
Right-Click -> features-->driver-->driver update--> search from desktop/ computer---> search from list---> and now choose your installed driver not the 15.201 this driver is from windows 10 and dont work.

I think you played your games actually with your integrated intel graphics.

Next step is to choose switchable graphics with your crimson software.
But this is difficult to explain, but there are good videos on youtube.

Comment: That's not it, the driver running on my system was the latest Crimson driver, downloaded from AMD. The windows driver works just fine, but it doesn't work with Catalyst. Also, I know how switchable graphics work, I switched to the integrated Intel Card and it worked fine.